# Base de datos no recibe/guarda Datos desde Formulario php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo este problema y no entiendo donde podria estar el error, al apretar el submit final no guarda nada en la BD. Si necesitan otro fragmento de codigo o mostrar la BD me dicen.

Espero me puedan indicar el por que no esta guardando, saludos!

Aqui el form que uso, al apretar el input submit `name="btn_registrar"` deberia llamar a `registro_usuarios.php` :

```
<?php
    require_once "funciones/db.php";
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_formulario.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gradDynamic">
    <h1 class="color_letra"> Regístrate y sé parte de nuestra comunidad!</h1>
    <!-- multistep form -->
    <form role="form" action="funciones/registro_usuarios.php" id="msform" method="POST">
      <div id="signupalert" style="display:none">
        <p>Error</p>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <!-- progressbar -->
      <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Creacion Cuenta</li>
        <li>Detalles Personales</li>
        <li>Redes sociales</li>

      </ul>
      <!-- fieldsets -->
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Crea tu Cuenta</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"> Paso 1</h3>
        <input type="text" name="run" placeholder="Run alumno Inacap" >
        <input type="text"  name="email"  placeholder="E-mail institucional" >
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"  >
        <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirmar Password" >
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Siguiente"  >
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Detalles Personales</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Muestrate al mundo!</h3>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"  >
        <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" >
        <select class="" name="carrera">
          <option selected disabled hidden>Selecciona Tu Carrera</option>
          <option value="1"> Diseño Web & mobile</option>
          <option value="2"> Diseño Grafico</option>
          <option value="3"> Diseño Profesional</option>
        </select>
        <textarea name="about" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder=" Describete a ti mismo!"></textarea >
          <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Anterior"  />
          <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Siguiente" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <h2 class="fs-title">Redes Sociales</h2>
          <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Tu presencia en las Redes Sociales</h3>
          <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" >
          <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook">
          <input type="text" name="linkedin" placeholder="Linkedin" >
          <input type="text" name="github" placeholder="Github" >
          <input type="text" name="pinterest" placeholder="Pinterest">
          <input type="text" name="instagram" placeholder="Instagram" >
          <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Atras" />
          <input type="submit" name="btn_registrar" class="submit action-button" value="Crear" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <div class="cuadro">
        <img src="css/titulo.png" width="200" height="100">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js'></script>
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Aqui la parte del archivo funciones/registro_usuarios.php  :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn_registrar'])){
 include_once 'db.php';

// Guardamos los Post del Registro.php
 $run = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['run']);  //mysqli_real_escape_string -- Metodo seguridad, convierte
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);  //a texto dentro de input para prevenir sql inyection !
 $pass =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['pass']);
 $cpass =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['cpass']);
 $nombre =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['nombre']);
 $apellido =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['apellido']);
 $about =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['about']);

//Errores! - Chequeo para campos en blancos!

if(empty($run) || empty($email) || empty($pass) || empty($cpass) || empty($nombre) || empty($apellido) ){
  header("Location: ../registro.php?registro=empty");
  exit();
} else {
  // Chequeamos si los caracteres del  input  son validos
  if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $nombre) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $apellido) || !preg_match("/^[1-9]*$/", $run) ){
  header("Location: ../registro.php?registro=invalid");
  exit();

} else { // Chequeamos si email es valido
  if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../registro.php?registro=email");
    exit();
  } else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre ='$nombre'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $resultadoCheck = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

    if($resultadoCheck > 0){
      header("Location: ../registro.php?registro=nombreRegistrado");
      exit();
    } else {
      // Hashing la password
      $hashedpass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

      // Ingresamos al usuario dentro de la database!

      $sql ="INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, apellido, pass, run, email, about) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$hashedpass', '$run', '$email', '$about'); ";
      mysqli_query($link, $sql);
      header("Location: ../registro.php?registro=success");
      exit();
    }
  }
}

}

} else {
  header("Location: ../registro.php");
  exit();
}
?>
```

y por ultimo mi archivo funciones/db.php  :

```
<?php
 function conectar(){
    $servidor = "localhost:3306";
    $usuario = "root";
    $password = "";
    $baseDatos = "valpocrea";
    $link = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password, $baseDatos);
return $link;
}
?>
```

Comment: me imagino que luego de incluir **db.php** en **funciones/registro_usuarios.php** debas crear la variable $link de esta manera: $link = conectar();

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas puede añadir su respuesta. No sé si sea el único error pero de todas maneras es el más importante.

Comment: Hola chicos, no ese el problema, ya que se excuta al  llamarl la db con inlcude_once!

Comment: @BastienWevar entonces como tarea será de revisar en que consiste [include_once](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include-once.php) , **solo incluye** la porción de código a su archivo, pero **nunca** realiza el llamado a la función. por lo tanto nunca obtiene el `$link` de conexión. _(espero Daniel añada como respuesta, si no, añadiré)_

Comment: Interesante por que sin llamar a mi funcion como indica, igual me hace la conexion. Esta curioso esto.

Comment: Aprovecho para darte la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. He editado tu pregunta quitando los *code snippet*, los cuáles existen **para código que se pueda probar 100%**, no es tu caso. Cuando eso no es posible, los *code snippet*   en vez de ayudar, dificultan la comprensión del código. El área de composición de preguntas tiene otra opción para ese tipo de código, lo puedes pegar, luego seleccionar y presionar en los símbolos **`{ }`**. Si el código está correctamente identado, eso también ayuda a comprenderlo/analizarlo mejor. Por favor, tenlo en cuenta para futuras preguntas.

Comment: @A.Cedano, Muchas gracias! Lo tendre en cuenta para futuras consultas, soy nuevo y se agradecen estas correciones, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta activar el reporte de errores en tu script funciones/registro_usuarios.php con

```
error_reporting(E_ALL) ;
ini_set("display_errors",1);
```

y comenta los header para que puedas ver el error.

Actualiza la pregunta con los detalles del error que obtuviste.

Answer (score 0):

No inicializas la conexión. Justo antes de la llamada a mysqli_query pon:

```
$link = conectar();
```

Comment: Otra posibilidad sería, en caso de que `db.php` lo único que haga sea crear la conexión, sacar el código de la función `conectar()`, pues tenerlo en una función sólo tendría sentido si el archivo sirviera para otras cosas. De ese modo, se podría incluir y usar el objeto `$link` sin más complicaciones.

Comment: La verdad que sacando la creacion de funcion y solo poniendolo, como indican arriba de este comentario. funciona igual. Es curioso que creando la funcion y no llamandola, igual funciona haciendo el include_once